# Centos Web Panel: SMTP

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot, centos-web-panel

When I send mails to gmail and yahoo everything is perfect i got SPF, DKIM, DMARC passed on gmail but when I send to hotmail mail i got:

> Queued mail for delivery -> 250 2.1.5 on the hotmail smtp servers (not mine)

I got no errors except this one above. I use Centos Web Panel with postfix and dovecot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the bounce message you receive is due to the receivers end. Kindly verify the validity of the recipient address and if the receiving server is configured to receive messages correctly.

May I know how many emails do you send in an hour?

If it is more than 200 then please try to reduce the recipients on the email you are trying to send and let me know if the issue still persists.